# Maintaining URL parameters across page views

Tags: django, sorting, filter, restful-url

I am writing a Django application and would like to provide optional filters and sort options to the results displayed. I would like to represent these optional filters and sort options using RESTful URLs such as

- /
- /tags/tag1/
- /tags/tag1/page2
- /tags/tag1/by/newest-desc/
- /tags/tag1/by/newest-desc/page2

etc.

How should I maintain the existing URL filters or sort options across page views? I have tried using

```
{% url 'list-view' tags=tags sort=sort-option %}
```

in my templates but these cause problems when viewing pages without both tags and sort-option parameters already set.

This problem is very similar to [Using both sort & filter on a QuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379841/using-both-sort-filter-on-a-queryset) but I am really looking for a RESTful URL solution, not a GET parameter or session state variable solution.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Niall

Answer (score 0):

Sort order should be a `GET` parameter as should be the page number.  They'll be much easier to handle that way.

Think about it this way:  the `/tags/tag1` indicate what you are viewing.  The other two indicate certain display options.

Comment: Hey said he didn't want a get parameter solution.